# Macbook 2010 running Ubuntu - no battery - how do I have it automatically restart after a power failure?

Tags: power-management, battery, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro running Ubuntu from 2010. Since its Lithium Ion battery was swollen, I removed the battery and now have it running from a UPS - uninterrupted power supply.
Sometimes, the power goes off and the Macbook turns off.
How do I have it restart on its own after this sort of a power supply failure? As of now, if the power fails or the UPS turns off - it will not restart on its own and I will have to long press the power button to switch it on again.
Was wondering how to have it work similar to a Raspberry Pi - switch off - it powers on again persistently when it receives power again.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/212434/how-to-reboot-after-power-failure-for-mac-mini-running-ubuntu - there are some promising answers there